# Extracting Certain Contents from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp

We are working on a project where we need to retrieve main contents from a particular list. Since our project needs stanford parser, we used

```
hello = "This is a sample text"
result = list(sdp.raw_parse(hello))
```

we tried printing it, which was like

```
 In: print(result[0])
 Out:  {0: {'address': 0,
                     'ctag': 'TOP',
                     'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'root': [5]}),
                     'feats': None,
                     'head': None,
                     'lemma': None,
                     'rel': None,
                     'tag': 'TOP',
                     'word': None},
                 1: {'address': 1,
                     'ctag': 'DT',
                     'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                     'feats': '_',
                     'head': 5,
                     'lemma': '_',
                     'rel': 'nsubj',
                     'tag': 'DT',
                     'word': 'This'},
                 2: {'address': 2,
                     'ctag': 'VBZ',
                     'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                     'feats': '_',
                     'head': 5,
                     'lemma': '_',
                     'rel': 'cop',
                     'tag': 'VBZ',
                     'word': 'is'},
                 3: {'address': 3,
                     'ctag': 'DT',
                     'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                     'feats': '_',
                     'head': 5,
                     'lemma': '_',
                     'rel': 'det',
                     'tag': 'DT',
                     'word': 'a'},
                 4: {'address': 4,
                     'ctag': 'NN',
                     'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                     'feats': '_',
                     'head': 5,
                     'lemma': '_',
                     'rel': 'compound',
                     'tag': 'NN',
                     'word': 'sample'},
                 5: {'address': 5,
                     'ctag': 'NN',
                     'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                                         {'compound': [4],
                                          'cop': [2],
                                          'det': [3],
                                          'nsubj': [1]}),
                     'feats': '_',
                     'head': 0,
                     'lemma': '_',
                     'rel': 'root',
                     'tag': 'NN',
                     'word': 'text'}})
```

what i actually want is to print just the

```
'word' : 'this'
```

Please do help me with a solution, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`print(result[0][1]['word'])` will work straight forward but if you dont know which index hold 'this' value, you should iterate throuh loop plus put some codition.

This can be accomplished by list comprehension or you can use map.

Please put some more detail in order to get what you required.

Comment: To be more simpler, i want to retrieve like                                                    `1: {'address': 1, 'ctag': 'DT' , 'head': 5, 'rel': 'nsubj', 'tag': 'DT', 'word': 'This'}`

Comment: you can try this,   print(result[0][1]  and one more thing where did you face issue.